# Does jquery mobile behave differently on different devices

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a specific problem that leads me to a general question.

My specific problem is that a css style that I have written,

```
[data-role='collapsible'] > :first-child .ui-btn-inner
```

works fine in a pc browser, but not on my android 2.3.

Since I have not figured out how to debug android sites (*like firebug for FF*), I cannot look at the android-rendered page to see if **maybe** the jqm framework did something different to `data-role='collapsible'` on the android.

So my question: does the jqm framework treat pages differently depending on the device?

Comment: More like does the device handle javascript differently.

Comment: I recommend researching CSS caveats for Android 2.3 to make sure your selector actually works in that platform.

Comment: ++ @Jasper For remote debugging you may try http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/ or http://debug.phonegap.com/